# Accessing Firebird Database Remotely using JDBC

Tags: jdbc

I would like to access a Firebird database remotely using DBeaver and have had little success. DBeaver utilises the FirebirdSQL JDBC driver.

We have been presented with the following error message:

- unavailable database [SQLState:08001, ISC error code:335544375]
  unavailable database
  unavailable database
- (when specifying the alias as the path)I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "clinplus"; Error while trying to open file; The system cannot find the file specified.  [SQLState:08001, ISC error code:335544344]
  I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "clinplus"
  I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "clinplus"
  Error while trying to open file; The system cannot find the file specified.

What we have tried

- Connect to database via the database server: This works fine.
- Disabled Windows Firewall: Still not working
- Mapped the location of the specific database files as network drives: Still not working

Further information

- URI Template: jdbc:firebirdsql://{host}:{port}/{file}

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this myself pretty quickly. I didn't understand the path was relative to the server it was connecting to. My problem was my connection string appeared as: `jdbc:firebirdsql://HOST:3050/\\HOST\path\to\db` where it needed to be `jdbc:firebirdsql://HOST:3050/C:/path/to/db`. C:\ is the C drive on the host.